# iOS: WkWebView and Safari Mobile behaves differently

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have created a simple hybrid app that uses WkWebView to load and render my company's single page web application in iOS 9.3. For the most part, the user experience of using WkWebView vs. Safari Mobile is very similar but **not** exactly the same. For example, in WkWebView, the scrolling behaviour is broken one for one of my web pages. However, in Safari Mobile, the scrolling behaviour is **not** broken for that same page.

This makes me believe that Safari Mobile is using a different version of webkit that WkWebView uses. Can someone confirm this? Is there a way to configure WkWebView to behave **exactly** the way Safari Mobile behaves?

Comment: I have the same issue. I couldn't find out how to solve this problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm also Facing the Same Issue. in Safari my Login JavaScript code form works fine, but in UIWebView and in WKWebView that form isn't loading. Please help out about this... any solution you found ?